# LCD 35 Kuman driver on Kodi

Tags: kodi, driver, osmc

Is there a way to use the driver from the 35-inch LCD touchscreen from Kuman?

I tried it, but my Raspberry Pi didn't answer with SSH after I installed it. On the HDMI output is a black screen and no connection any more with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [this 3.5 inch LCD touch screen](http://kumantech.com/kuman-35-inch-tft-lcd-display-480x320-rgb-pixels-touch-screen-monitor-for-raspberry-pi-3-2-model-b-b-a-a-module-spi-interface-with-touch-pen-sc06_p0014.html), which connects via SPI and needs a special Raspbian image with their own driver, I wouldn't count on being able to switch back and forth between using the LCD screen and HDMI.

So if you downloaded their special image, that corresponds to your Pi, either Pi 2 or Pi 3, then imaged an SD Card and the LCD screen still doesn't work, the only option is to contact Kuman.

And to be able to go back to using your Pi via HDMI, best bet is to reimage SD Card with standard Raspbian image.